# M-Audio Jamlab & LMMS / Ubuntu Studio

Tags: audio

Is there a way to get *M-Audio **Jamlab*** working with LMMS and / or Ubuntu Studio in elementary OS?
I haven't found an appropriate driver yet...

---

I'm on a Macbook (3,1 - late 2007).

Answer (score 1):

To get guitars or other **"non-digital" (MIDI)** equipment working with Linux, you will need to learn how to use JACK. Using a program called **Catia** from the **KXStudio repository** is much much easier than **QJackCtl**.

You will also need to make sure `pavucontrol` and `pulseaudio-module-jack` is installed.

My favorite cable so far has been a **Rocksmith USB guitar cable**, though they go out after regular use in a few months. Buying any audio cable with an LED light on it doesn't make any sense to me (buzzing).

## Quick disclaimer

You may not be able to get **LMMS** working with JACK since I think it is technically dependent on **Wine** to work. If not, and still want to record, you could still try **Ardour** or **Audacity**.

Open **PulseAudio Volume Control** (`pavucontrol`) and look under configuration and make sure the **USB M-Audio JamLab device** is set to input only *(I doubt you'll get both in/out working)*. Then, go to Input Devices tab and make sure JamLab device is the one being used. Go to **Output Devices** tab and make sure audio is going to the headphones or whatever you want.

**Open Catia** --> **Tools** --> **Jack Server** --> **Configure Jack**

Select **Duplex Mode** and make sure the **Input Device** and the **Output Devices** are correct.

Click **OK**, **Next**, go to **Tools** --> **Jack Server** --> **Start Jack Server**

Open the applications you want to use **Catia** to pipe audio through. Linux has programs like **Guitarix** and **Rakarrack** for guitar. You move the virtual cables in **Catia** around to make connections.

## BE AWARE

That just because you stop the Jack server, you will also have to run `killall jack` or use `htop` to find and stop the process. If your audio still acts funny afterwards, try `killall pulseaudio`.

Your are kind of lucky, even though you have an older MacBook, because I have a newer one with an actual HDMI port *(so video and audio)*, and it has been nothing but hell trying to get Jack and PulseAudio to work properly. I have to kill `pulseaudio` to get it to reset just for normal things like Kodi or Firefox videos sometimes. And, sometimes my HDMI as an option disappears all together. If you plan to buy a newer laptop soon for Linux-only and want an actual HDMI port, don't get an Apple.

Comment: Thank you, @TheOuterLinux, for this very good information.